# SQL Anywhere 17 & PHP 8.x.y on Linux

Tags: php, linux, sqlanywhere

I want to install PHP SQL Anywhere 17 module for **PHP 8.1 version**.

I am using the **PHP 8.0.0 module** provided in the SAP documentation (https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/SQLANY/The+SAP+SQL+Anywhere+PHP+Module).
The driver is installed correctly.

However, when I fill in the module path in my *apache2/php.ini* config like this: `extension=/opt/sqlanywhere17/lib64/php-8.0.0_sqlanywhere_r.so` the extension does not load.

I also added the environment variable in */etc/apache2/envvars*:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/opt/sqlanywhere17/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

That's all I can find in the SAP documentation.

This is what PHP returns to me:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: sqlanywhere: Unable to initialize module
```

Is there anything else to define? Is the SQL Anywhere version for PHP 8.0.0 compatible with a PHP version 8.1.y or even 8.2.y?

I am using a Debian 11.

I tried to initialize the PHP module of SQL Anywhere in the **php.ini** configuration, I expected to be able to use this module afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

It has been released on their official page: https://help.sap.com/docs/SUPPORT_CONTENT/sqlany/3362971282.html

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot use module compiled for PHP 8.0 in PHP 8.1 nor in PHP 8.2.

As far as I am aware, there are currently no oficially provided packages for PHP 8.1+. And as SQL Anywhere is owned by SAP, you can only get SAP-ey [response](https://answers.sap.com/questions/13610937/sql-anywhere-php-module-for-81-or-80.html) as regards to timeline:

> The precompiled PHP driver for SQL Anywhere is periodically updated. But that does not preclude you from building the driver as its source is released under the Apache License, Version 2.
> ... We are prohibited from announcing specific timeframes in advance of releases.